# What is the point of the boilerplate CRT function matherr?

Tags: c, disassembly, msvcrt, boilerplate

I wrote a basic "Hello World" program in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        printf("Hello World!\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Then, I compiled it in MSVC from the command-line as such:

`cl hello.c /Fd:hello.pdb /Zi /MD /link /NODEFAULTLIB:LIBCMT.LIB`

The command line arguments basically say "generate a PDB file and link with MSVCRT.LIB rather than LIBCMT.LIB".

Then, I disassembled the program and looked at the various boilerplate/CRT functions and found this in the disassembly, which was curious:

```
__matherr:
  00401550: 33 C0              xor         eax,eax
  00401552: C3                 ret
```

This is basically a function that always returns 0 in EAX whenever it's called. According to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3backsw.aspx) of this function, it returns 0 when there is a math error and non-0 when there isn't an error.

Does anyone have an answer as to why this function, which is supposed to return 0 in the case of a math error, is included in the executable and is hard-coded to *always* return 0?

Comment: You have the CRT source code on your machine, look in the vc/crt/src directory.  Note the comment: "The default matherr does nothing and returns 0".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`matherr`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/matherr.3.html) is supposed to be called from various math functions if a math exception is detected. The default implementation does nothing. On some platforms, it's possible to selectively replace C library functions with user-defined code ("function interposition" on ELF systems), so you could implement your own math error handler. AFAIK, this isn't possible with Portable Executables (PE) on Windows. I guess that `matherr` is part of the CRT only for compatibility reasons.